# Using Leibniz' formula to show the $(2n)$th derivative of $(2x^2 + 3x +1)\sin x$ is $(-1)^n(2x^2+3x-8n^2+4n+1)\sin x+(-1)^{n+1}(8nx+6n)\cos x$ wrt $x$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, binomial-coefficients, power-series, intuition

If I let $f=f(x)=\sin x$ and $g=g(x)=2x^2+3x+1$ and $D=$ First derivative wrt $x$, $D^2=$ Second derivative wrt $x$ and $D^n=$ $nth$ derivative wrt $x$ then,

Leibniz' formula states that $\displaystyle D^n(fg)=(D^nf)g+n(D^{n-1}f)(Dg)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}(D^{n-2}f)(D^2g)+\cdots +f(D^ng)$

Replacing $n$ with $2n$ yields $\displaystyle D^{2n}(fg)=(D^{2n}f)g+2n(D^{2n-1}f)(Dg)+\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2!}(D^{2n-2}f)(D^2g)+.....+f(D^{2n}g)$

I know that $g=2x^2+3x+1$ and $Dg=4x+3$ and $D^2g=4$ and $D^3g=0$ etc.

Also $f=\sin x$, $Df=\cos x$, $D^2f=-\sin x$, and $D^3f=-\cos x$, $D^4f=\sin x$ and cycle repeats.

So in general $D^{2r}f=(-1)^r \sin x$ and $D^{2r+1}f=(-1)^r \cos x$.

Therefore first term is $(D^{2n}f)g=(-1)^n \sin x(2x^2+3x+1)$

Second term is $2n(D^{2n-1}f)(Dg)=2n(-1)^n \cos x(4x+3)$

Third and final term is (as all subsequent terms are zero) $\displaystyle \frac{2n(2n-1)}{2!}(D^{2n-2}f)(D^2g)=n(2n-1)(-1)^n \sin x \times 4$.

Now I can tell you that the sum of these three terms above $\ne(-1)^n(2x^2+3x-8n^2+4n+1)\sin x+(-1)^{n+1}(8nx+6n)\cos x$.

Could someone please explain to me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You observed correctly that
$$D^{2r+1}f=(-1)^r\cos x$$
but then you wrote
$$D^{2n-1}f=(-1)^n\cos x\ ,$$
it should be
$$D^{2n-1}f=(-1)^{n-1}\cos x\ .$$
There is a similar error in your third term.

To get the given answer you will also need to note that $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Hi David thank you for your answer. I understood everything you explained apart from the part why $$D^{2n-1}f=(-1)^{n-1}\cos x\ ?$$ Could you please explain as simply as possible why $(-1)^{n-1}cosx$ is _correct_ and why $(-1)^ncosx$ is wrong? Thanks, with kind regards.

Comment: In $D^{2r+1}f=(-1)^r\cos x$, substitute $r=n-1$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Okay thanks. Could you please tell me why we substitute $r=n-1$?. You also said I made a similar error for the third term so should $r=n-2$ for that term? Sorry i'm still a bit confused. Regards.

Comment: Because if you substitute $r=n-1$ then $2r+1=2(n-1)+1=2n-2+1=2n-1$.  If you still don't get it then I very strongly recommend that you talk to your instructor because I'm not sure I really understand the difficulty and so it is hard to give you  helpful advice online.